# VSTS: How to organize user stories into deliverables without using the epic/feature

Tags: azure-devops

We are using Initiatives/Epics/Features to organize the User Stories into logic chunks. That works just fine.

But for larger projects we also deliver stuff for testing, and I need a way to group User Stories into these deliverables. I can't just create an Epic/Feature for that because I might need want to test half of one feature and half of another feature (plus I would break the logic grouping). So I need a system parallel to features to group user stories into deliverables.

I could use Tags for this, but I would like to have an object instead sp that I could add description, date etc.

Are there any ways of doing that in VSTS?

Comment: Maybe link one "Release" type of work item under stories?

Comment: @PanuOksala: can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: You could do a new work item with title "Release 1" and add all the work items under that as relative work items. Release work item could then contain the description, date etc.